# How to combine multiple xaml pages in one xaml page?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp-xaml

Is there any idea of master layout and child layouts in wpf for xaml pages?
I have one xaml file which I want to use in two different Xaml files with different Data but same UI.
I don't want to create same design two times, I just want to have only one xaml page on both places.

Comment: You could opt for building a UserControl and use it multiple times, each with it's own view model. Is that an option?

Comment: Have you checked the answer yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ContentControl` with different `ContentTemplate`. Define these `ContentTemplate` as `Resource`. Specify `DataType` in the `DataTemplate` of your `ContentTemplate`. And in different places just set appropriate `Content` of your `ContentControl` using `Binding`. This `Content` can be any property of any kind.

Eg;

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding View1}" />

<ContentControl Content="{Binding View2}" />
```

Beauty is `DataTemplate` is automatically picked up by the `ContentControl`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Anjum, I am trying to solve and understand these concepts. I will give you one up, as soon I reached to the requirement. Or I will come up with some new opportunity.